# Como puedo unir dos listas y enlazarlas entre si?

Tags: python, mysql

Hola necesito saber como se puede unir dos listas y enlazarlas para que me salgan de esta manera:

```
Codigo:66,Nombre:Pau Gasol,Procedencia:Spain,etc...


sql =f"SELECT * FROM jugadores WHERE codigo = '{codigo}'"         
mycursor.execute(sql)         
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()         
myresult2=['Codigo', 'Nombre', 'Procedencia', 'Altura', 'Peso', 'Posicion', 'Equipo']         
lista = [f"{x}:{y}" for x, y in zip(myresult2, myresult)]         
print(lista)
```

Esto es lo que me saca:

```
["Codigo::(1, 'Corey Brever', 'Florida', '6-9', 185, 'F-G', 'Timberwolves')"]
```

Comment: ¿Quieres una lista o un diccionario?

Comment: Una lista mejor para luego hacer un print de esa lista

Comment: perdon por poner una respuesta soy nuevo.

Comment: `lista = [f"{x}:{y}" for x, y in zip(myresult2, myresult)]`

Comment: Hola no me funciona porque la cosa es que la lista myresult la he escrito para dar el ejemplo per en realidad es de una select de una base de datos y la salida es esa y no me funciona mira: `sql =f"SELECT * FROM jugadores WHERE codigo = '{codigo}'"
        mycursor.execute(sql)
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        myresult2=['Codigo', 'Nombre', 'Procedencia', 'Altura', 'Peso', 'Posicion', 'Equipo']
        lista = [f"{x}:{y}" for x, y in zip(myresult2, myresult)]
        print(lista)`

Comment: la salida es esta:["Codigo:(1, 'Corey Brever', 'Florida', '6-9', 185, 'F-G', 'Timberwolves')"]

Comment: Lo que preguntaste y lo que querías preguntar son dos cosas distintas.

Comment: si la verdad pero creia que era lo mismo y lo he preguntado asi porque era mas visual para que se podiera entender mejor

Comment: Lo corregí ya .